# I am installing the Detecto library in anaconda environment but it fails while importing

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda

As a source, I apply the guide here:
[Object Detection](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-custom-trained-object-detection-model-with-5-lines-of-code-713ba7f6c0fb)

I applied the `pip3 install detecto` command as shown here and it was successfully installed. But when I run python and try to run the detecto command, I get an error. How can I solve it?

Operation:

[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant part(s) of that link in the post itself. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Yes, I know the codes are not sent as pictures. But I use fish at the terminal, when I throw it as code, the writing is very complicated. So I took it as a picture to make it easy to read. Otherwise believe me it would be impossible to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can import detecto directly. Use `from detecto import <lib>` . Try `from detecto.core import Model` and see if it works in your terminal

Comment: It didn't work, it still keeps giving the same error.

`Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:32:53)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from detecto.core import Model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'detecto'
>>>`

Comment: Try `conda list` in your BitimeProj environment and check if you see any detecto packages. If you don't then your screenshot makes sense as pip3 did not install the detecto package in your conda environment but rather in your global default python environment. You should install detecto with conda instead

Comment: By the way you can use pip to install a package in a conda environment. User `pip install detecto` and NOT `pip3 install detecto`

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved with `pip install detecto` command. Why is pip3 not working so much? I installed other packages with pip3.

Comment: Read `mingwandroid's` explanation here https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9558

Comment: @AhmetTunahanYeniyayla _Why is pip3 not working so much? I installed other packages with pip3._ What other packages? Be careful, take a look at https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.